# Hadoop hdfs namenode is throwing an error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Full list of error:

```
hb@localhost:/etc/hadoop/conf$ sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start
 * Starting Hadoop namenode: 
starting namenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-localhost.out
12/09/10 14:41:09 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = localhost/127.0.0.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.0.0-cdh4.0.1
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/kfs-0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/aspectjrt-1.6.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-xc-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-json-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.cloudera.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jetty-6.1.26.cloudera.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/zookeeper-3.4.3-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/avro-1.5.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/core-3.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-annotations-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-auth.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/snappy-java-1.0.3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/zookeeper-3.4.3-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/avro-1.5.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1-tests.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//hadoop-hdfs.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/netty-3.2.3.Final.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/snappy-java-1.0.3.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/junit-4.8.2.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/jdiff-1.0.9.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/avro-1.5.4.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-common.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-api.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-site.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-api-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-common-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//hadoop-yarn-site-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//*
STARTUP_MSG:   build = file:///var/lib/jenkins/workspace/generic-package-ubuntu64-12-04/CDH4.0.1-Packaging-Hadoop-2012-06-28_17-01-57/hadoop-2.0.0+91-1.cdh4.0.1.p0.1~precise/src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common -r 4d98eb718ec0cce78a00f292928c5ab6e1b84695; compiled by 'jenkins' on Thu Jun 28 17:39:19 PDT 2012
************************************************************/
12/09/10 14:41:10 WARN impl.MetricsConfig: Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-namenode.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
hb@localhost:/etc/hadoop/conf$ cat hdfs-site.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--Autogenerated by Cloudera CM on 2012-09-03T10:13:30.628Z-->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.https.address</name>
    <value>localhost:50470</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.https.port</name>
    <value>50470</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
    <value>localhost:50070</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
    <value>134217728</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make that WARN go away just place a `hadoop-metrics2.properties` in your configuration folder `/etc/hadoop/conf`. In the distribution of hadoop you downloaded there should be sample/default config files for each configuration file and a default of that file would be fine.